# How to debug thread

Tags: android, eclipse

I have kept debugger in these two places but when it hits debugger1 its skips debugger2 and not debugging the code inside it. How to make or hit the debugger2 in thread.

```
 t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
               public void run() {
                    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    debugger1---->      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
    debugger2---->              public void run() {
                                if (flag == 0) {
                                    Timer.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            t.start();
```

Comment: Please put android in the tags not the title. If you don't do that it is very unlikely that anyone who can answer your question will see it.

Comment: Have you tried putting the break-point on the "if" line rather than the `public void run() {` line?

Comment: Also once the debugger breaks on the first break-point, you won't be able to "Step" to the second one, as it's on a different thread - you'll need to continue execution of the program in order to hit the second break-point.